# positive, negative and neutral adjectives

Tags: adjectives

In English there are positive, negative and neutral(both positive and negative) adjectives describing personality traits. My question is that are "serious, silly, talkative,nervous" considered as neutral adjectives? Of course, I know words are used subjectively and it depends on the context or the tone of voice but I'm not sure about these adjectives. To my understanding "silly and nervous" are definitely negative but I've got no idea about "serious".
I need the correct answer as the day after tomorrow I have to talk about this topic.
 Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think that any of those adjectives could be used in negative, neutral, or positive ways - as you've said, it depends on context.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely a matter of taste and context. *Silly* is usually negative, though could be neutral-to-positive describing a comedian, for example. *Nervous* is also negative in most situations. *Talkative* is closer to neutral, though (for my tastes) slightly negative. *Serious* is the most neutral of those words, though it has the negative meaning "lacking a sense of humour" as well as the positive connotations "trustworthy", "dedicated", "sincere".

It might be worth considering their antonyms. *Nervous* is the opposite of ["bold, brave, calm, cool..."](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/nervous) - all positive. Likewise, *Silly* is the opposite of "intelligent, sensible, mature, wise", but *serious* is the opposite of the negative terms ["deceptive, dishonest, insincere, untrustworthy"](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/serious).

A minor point: some of these words change their emphasis if not describing "personality traits", so *nervous* meaning "pertaining to the nerves" is neutral, and *serious* as in "a serious situation" is negative.